# How to send the arguments to post back dialog

Tags: botframework

I have created a `post back dialog` but trying to post some arguments while calling the postback dialog in microsoft bot framework in v#4 doesn't work as expected.

I have written this code to call the post back dialog from hero card. Here i am able to call the post back but i'm not able to send values(arguments) to postback dialog.

```
var card1 = CardFactory.heroCard(
                    Name,
                    Address1+", "City",
                    CardFactory.images([Image]),
                    CardFactory.actions([
                        {
                            type: 'postBack',
                            title: Service,
                            value: PostBack_DIALOG,
                            text: 'arguments for postback dialog'
                        },
                        {
                            type: 'call',
                            title: phone ,
                            value: "tel:" + phoneNumber
                        }
                    ])
```

Please suggest how to send the arguments to post back dialog in bot framework v#4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this via sending the argument, not as part of the card, but as part of a successive `sendActivities` step once the hero card has rendered and the user has selected a button.

In the following code example, I have two steps. One for rendering the card and one for sending the data after the user has interacted with the card. In the first step, called `postBackCardStep`, I am capturing a previous value from a suggested action where the user selected either 'blue' or 'green'. That value is then passed in the `Service` button when that button is pressed.

In the second step, called `postBackPostStep`, I capture and send the user's selection in `resultDetails`. I also define a property, called `postBackArg`, and send a property vlaue for validation on the client side. I send this in a `data` dictionary object in a `sendActivities` activity. This allows me to send, as one action, both a message and the data.

```js
async postBackCardStep ( stepContext ) {
  const PostBack_DIALOG = stepContext.context.activity.text;

  const reply = { type: ActivityTypes.Message };

  const postBackBtn = { type: ActionTypes.PostBack, title: 'Service', value: PostBack_DIALOG }
  const callBtn = { type: ActionTypes.Call, title: 'Phone', value: '123-456-7890' }

  const card = CardFactory.heroCard(
    '<Name>',
    '<Address>',
    ['<link to some image>'],
    [
      postBackBtn,
      callBtn
    ]
  );

  reply.attachments = [ card ];

  await stepContext.context.sendActivity( reply );
  return { status: DialogTurnStatus.waiting };
}

async postBackPostStep ( stepContext ) {
  const resultDetails = stepContext.context.activity.text;

  const data = { value: resultDetails, postBackArg: 'true' };
  await stepContext.context.sendActivities( [
    { text: `Sending ${ resultDetails } via postBack`, type: 'message' },
    { name: 'data', type: 'event', channelData: { 'data': data } }
  ] );
  return await stepContext.next();
}
```

Next, in the web chat script in the html page, I have the following code. I create a store, create and name an event, and pass the acquired data from the bot into that event. I then create an event listener that validates the data by checking if the received data is an `event` type and a `postBackArg` value of 'true' (this value should be passed from the bot as a string and validated as a string). If both checks pass, then the console message is posted with the values. The store is then passed into `renderWebChat`.

```html
const store = window.WebChat.createStore( {}, ( { dispatch } ) => next => action => {
  if ( action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/INCOMING_ACTIVITY' ) {
    const event = new Event('incomingActivity');

    event.data = action.payload.activity;
    window.dispatchEvent(event);
  }

  return next( action );
} );

window.addEventListener('incomingActivity', ({ data }) => {
  const type = data.type;
  if (type === 'event' && data.channelData.data.postBackArg === 'true') {
    console.log('DATA ', data);
    const resultDetails = data.channelData.data.value;
    const args = data.channelData.data.postBackArg;
    console.log(`Received a message from the bot (${resultDetails}) with argument value ${args}.`);
  }
} );

window.WebChat.renderWebChat( {
  directLine: directLine,
  store
}, document.getElementById( 'webchat' ) );
document.querySelector( '#webchat > *' ).focus();
```

[image]

Here, you can see the data has successfully been passed from the bot to the page which, as specified in the `incomingActivity` event listener, only occurs if the correct data properties were passed and successfully validated.
[image]

Unless I'm much mistaken, at this point you should be good to go!

Hope of help!